# Error when using gb4e.sty and graphicx.sty packages

Tags: graphics, errors, gb4e

My code as follow:

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{book}           
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{../Files_art/11127_003_fig_001.eps}

\end{document}
```

Which creates the error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\gb@ifnextchar #1#2#3->
                       \let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserv...
l.7 ...raphics{../Files_art/11127_003_fig_001.eps}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

but without the package "`gb4e`" the code works fine. Please suggest me what went wrong, note I'm using MikTeX 2.9 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\noautomath` tag solved my issue, thanks...